# TypeScript class failing

Tags: typescript

I am not able to transpile the following class:

```
class DataService {
    styles: Object[];
    selectedStyle: Object;
    selectedChildStyle: Object;
    
    constructor() {
        this.styles = [{
            "name": "Parent",
            "child": {}
        }];
        
        this.selectedStyle = this.styles[0];
        
        // THE BELOW LINES CREATE PROBLEM
        if (this.selectedStyle.child && this.selectedStyle.child.length)
            this.selectedChildStyle = this.selectedStyle.child[0];
        else
            this.selectedChildStyle = null;
    }
}
```

This doesn't let me `npm start` the app. It gives a weird error with code `ELIFECYCLE` if I keep the last four lines uncommented.

Comment: Could you at least tell what error message you're getting.

Comment: Don't get any proper error for this

Comment: Then how do you know it's failing?

Comment: npm start gives a weird error with code ELIFECYCLE when these 4 lines are uncommented..i have got the answer..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `selectedStyle` as any;

```
selectedStyle: any; // This is the change

class DataService {
    styles: Object[];
    selectedStyle: any; // This is the change
    selectedChildStyle: Object;

    constructor() {
        this.styles = [{
            "name": "Parent",
            "child": {}
        }];

        this.selectedStyle = this.styles[0];

        if (this.selectedStyle.child && this.selectedStyle.child.length)
            this.selectedChildStyle = this.selectedStyle.child[0];
        else
            this.selectedChildStyle = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lakshay any means defining the object as a dynamic one, I think you should read some articles and watch some videos regarding TypeScript

Comment: thanks Dor..yes i shd :)..pls share the link if u have one..thanks again

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using `Object` as the type of `this.selectedStyle`, and `Object` does not have a field named `child`.

If you want the compiler to know about the types then you need to define those, something like:

```
interface Style {
    name: string;
    child: Style[];
}

class DataService {
    styles: Style[];
    selectedStyle: Style;
    selectedChildStyle: Style;

    constructor() {
        this.styles = [{
            "name": "Parent",
            "child": [<Style> {}]
        }];

        this.selectedStyle = this.styles[0];

        // THE BELOW LINES CREATE PROBLEM
        if (this.selectedStyle.child && this.selectedStyle.child.length)
            this.selectedChildStyle = this.selectedStyle.child[0];
        else
            this.selectedChildStyle = null;
    }
}
```